# How can I show someone that I am a good listener?

Tags: friends, relationships

## Scenario:

I am a male and I have this female friend, who I consider to be one of my closest. She has opened up to me very slightly over the past year, telling me some deep things that have happened.

I have done the same but I feel as if my choice of telling her is influenced by her. She constantly encourages me to tell her things. There is a big difference between how much she has opened up to me and how much I have opened up to her. When I asked once why she doesn't open up to me she tells me that I'm not a good listener (which according to several others isn't true) and I was surprised at this.

## Question:

How can I show her that I am a good listener?

Comment: I think "should opening up be equal" is just a matter of pure opinion.  Do you have a goal, like, "How can I demonstrate that I am a good listener?" or "How can I ask my friend to open up to me more?"

Comment: Could you add *how* you normally listen to her? This is going to be hard, I know, but as body language and reactions can tell a lot in this case, try and think of a way to describe it, if you can. That will help avoid getting answers that tell you to do things you already do, or that don't address an underlying problem. Do you look at her, or gaze off into the distance? Do you from time to time acknowledge having heard what she says (nodding, backchannels) or not at all? Do you show undestanding of what she said by sometimes repeating her words, do you empathize (or not at all)?

Comment: In addition to that: Did she say why she thinks you're not a good listener? That's perhaps the easiest way to start thinking about how you usually listen/how you perhaps should act when listening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think an easy way to show someone you're actively involved and attentive to what they're saying is **asking them questions**.

Sure, you can sit there and listen to every last word they utter, but that doesn't necessarily show them that you're *actually* listening to what they're saying.

Asking a question shows that: "hey, I want you to explain *X* point better so I can understand your situation even more". It might not be easy to do at first if it doesn't come naturally; sometimes it just takes practice... you'll get better though. :)

Here's an example situation I've been in myself. My friend said something like:

> My mom never bakes me a cake for my birthday. It makes me really sad.

Then I'd follow up with a question:

> I'm really sorry to hear that. Why won't she make you a cake?

Notice, that I expressed concern and then asked a question. You **don't** want to ask question after question without giving any input at all; that'll just make it seem like you're interrogating them. Find a good balance between the two and naturally by asking questions you'll find more things to add to the conversation.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t “show” them you are a good listener. You just listen to them.

From your post, it seems you are not aware of how she feels and thinks. Otherwise her comment would not take you by surprise.

Maybe start by asking her feedback with some specific examples, so that you can understand her perspectives through those incidents and how you could improve in specific areas. After making improvements, ask for feedback again. It can be encouraging to see how yourself improve and bond with your friend better.

Answer (score 0):

This is tricky, but it's something we all have to deal with every day.

Communication is very much a two-way street.

It's possible that what she really means when she says you aren't a good listener is that you aren't saying the things she wants you to say. There's no magic formula for knowing what she wants. You just have to pay attention and try to get a feel for what she responds to positively over time.

Some people just want you to listen and show support and empathy. Some people want you to listen and give what they consider the "right" feedback. Some people just want you to listen to everything they have to say, but don't really care to listen to what you have to say (which is pretty selfish but many people are like this).

It's also possible she's just more introverted and much slower to open up than you are. She has to trust you completely before she opens up, and it might take you a long time to earn her trust. 
Just keep trying and pay close attention to what she seems to like or respond to the most. And remember that it's not completely dependent on you.